MIME type Error in Web Browser for Angular using Firebase
For a while now, anytime I make a push to my application, I will usually run into this error:

"Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec."

Whenever I create a build using "ng build --configuration production", I get this directory for my build: "dist/browser/assets".
dist has nothing but a 3rdpartlicenses.txt file, but browser has all the packets and contents of the build.
I've been doing a lot of research on this issue, but no one seems to have a definitive answer that isn't deprecated. Has anyone else that uses Angular run into this issue before? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.
P.S.
I am using Angular 17
angular.json:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "chime-in": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/icons"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "node_modules/@ngneat/hot-toast/src/styles/styles.css",
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "1mb",
                  "maximumError": "1.5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "baseHref": "/",
              "deployUrl": "/"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "chime-in:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "chime-in:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "chime-in:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/icons"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

firebase.json:
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log",
        "*.local"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",  
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ],
    "headers": [
      {
        "source": "/index.html",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/**/*.@(js|css|html)",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Cache-Control",
            "value": "max-age=31536000"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "source": "/**/*.js",
        "headers": [
          {
            "key": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/javascript"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

index.html:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ChimeIn</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body class="mat-typography">
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>


